# Form validation using JS

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am trying to run a check on all of my text fields using Javascript. I have looked at several examples here and other places to figure out what I am missing. I just can't get out of the weeds.

```
function validate(form){
    var textFieldsReq = document.getElementsByName('textFieldReq');

    for(i=0,n=textFieldsReq.length;i<n;i++){
    if ( !textFieldsReq.value ){
        alert ( 'You need to fill in ' + textFieldsReq[i] + '!');
        textFieldsReq.focus();
        return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

Your direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your if condition to `textFieldsReq[i]`

Comment: I added the following:       if(!textFieldsReq[i]){}; This did not resolve my issue.

Comment: Can you please post more code ? At least the html ? if possible, create a jsfiddle link.

Comment: here you go.... https://github.com/st2641/web_forms.git navigate to ReunionReg2015/public_html/

Comment: I went through my code and realized that I was taking Raghuveer too literally. Replacing 'textFieldsReq' with 'textFieldsReq[i]' fixed the issue. Thank you Raghuveer - please forgive my noobism!

Comment: Glad I was able to help ! Sorry I didnt see that you posted code for me to debug, but I am happy that your code is working now.

Answer (score 0):

HTML does this job for you! You can use **required** in the `<input>` tag:

```
<input type="text" required />
```